# Get Stats in Zabbix without Using Screens or Graphs

Tags: zabbix

I have no idea on how to see values that are being monitored without creating a graph or screen for it. Is this the only way?

I know the checks (items) use intervals and have history, how could I view that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to "Monitoring" -> "Latest data". There you can view graphs for any single item and, since Zabbix 2.4.0, you can even [view ad-hoc graphs for several items](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/introduction/whatsnew240#ad-hoc_graphs_for_several_items).

Comment: Well I can see why someone has downvoted my question. I stupidly assumed that this only picks up the latest data for triggered events. I did not realize that you are supposed to use the filter. Usually a filter would filter an already populated list. Anyways thanks!